# Prove that:$(P,\Vert\cdot\Vert)$ is not a Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $P$ is the space of all polynomial mappings on the field $\mathbb{R}$; $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ is a norm in $P$. Prove that:$(P,\Vert\cdot\Vert)$ is not a Banach space.

Answer (score 0):

exponential is a limit of polynomials and is not a polynomial.